# DAX TOTALYTD on two different cadandars

Tags: excel, dax, powerbi, powerquery

I am looking to create a YTD total, however, the year end date needs to change depending on the value in another column.  In other words, the fiscal year for group 1 would be from 11-1 (Nov-1) to 10-31 (Oct-31), while the fiscal year for group 2 would be from 7-1 (Jul-1) to 6-30 (Jul-30).  What I need to do is when calculating the fiscal year, I need the calculation for that year to be different depending on what group the line item is in.  So 2015 for group 1 would be 2014-11-01 to 2015-10-31 while 2015 for group 2 would be 2014-07-01 to 2014-06-30.  Please see an example table here (Please note that I do have a date table related to this one in order to create date functions):

```
         **Table 1**
-------------------------
Group |    Date    | Qty
  1   | 2014-10-01 |  1
  1   | 2014-11-01 |  1
  1   | 2015-01-01 |  2
  1   | 2015-05-01 |  1
  1   | 2015-10-31 |  2
  1   | 2015-11-01 |  1
  2   | 2014-06-01 |  1
  2   | 2014-07-01 |  1
  2   | 2014-12-25 |  2
  2   | 2015-01-01 |  1
  2   | 2015-06-30 |  2
  2   | 2015-07-01 |  1
```

With this information in mind, I need to create a YTDTOTAL function that will dynamically change the , parameter depending on what group the line item is in.  I thought of using an if statement, but realized that it wouldn't work on a measure.  Something like this:

```
Total $ Sold YTD = TOTALYTD([TOTAL $ Sold],directSQLDateTable[date],ALL(directSQLDateTable[date]), IIF([GROUP = "A","10/31","6/30"))
```

In the end, I would like to create an output similar to this (The "Group A YTD" and "Group B YTD" columns really are not needed, just wanted to add to demonstrate my example):

```
Year-Month | Total_Qty | Group A YTD | Group B YTD
--------------------------------------------------
  2014-07  |    1      |      0      |      1
  2014-08  |    1      |      0      |      1
  2014-09  |    1      |      0      |      1
  2014-10  |    2      |      1      |      1
  2014-11  |    2      |      1      |      1
  2014-12  |    4      |      1      |      3
  2015-01  |    7      |      3      |      4
  2015-02  |    7      |      3      |      4
  2015-03  |    7      |      3      |      4
  2015-04  |    7      |      3      |      4
  2015-05  |    8      |      4      |      4
  2015-06  |    10     |      4      |      6
  2015-07  |    5      |      4      |      1
  2015-08  |    5      |      4      |      1
  2015-09  |    5      |      4      |      1
  2015-10  |    7      |      6      |      1
  2015-11  |    2      |      1      |      1
  2015-12  |    2      |      1      |      1
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.  My apologies ahead of time if I didn't do that great of job explaining this or if I have left out a piece of info.

Thanks for any advice/help in advance!  You guys on here are the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TOTALYTD() includes everything you need for this.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634400.aspx)

```
TotalQty:= SUM(Table1[Qty])

QtyYTDGroup1:=
TOTALYTD(
    [TotalQty]
    ,DimDate[Date]
    ,Table1[Group] = 1
    ,"10/31"
)

QtyYTDGroup2:=
TOTALYTD(
    [TotalQty]
    ,DimDate[Date]
    ,Table1[Group] = 2
    ,"6/30"
)

TotalQtyYTD:= [QtyYTDGroup1] + [QtyYTDGroup2]
```

I can provide a detailed explanation if you want, but I think the function definition pretty much covers it.